# Как записать текст, введенный из консоли, в файл txt. на Си?

Tags: c

Для практики задали разработать алгоритм для поиска подстроки в строке, а так же чтоб там была работа с файлами. Проблема с работой с файлами. Как можно реализовать вывод текста, который вводишь в КОНСОЛИ, чтоб он из нее сохранялся в файл txt?

Способ изменения текста в самом коде не подойдет.

Язык программирования Си, запускаю в Visual studio

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вот простейшее решение в котором нет учёта длины вводимой строки (всё, что будет длинее 64 символов просто пропадёт.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // буфер, в котором мы храним информацию
    char buf[64] = "";

    // получаем ввод от пользователя
    fgets(buf, 64, stdin);

    // открываем нужный файл
    FILE *file = fopen("some.txt", "w");

    // пишем в файл
    fputs(buf, file);

    // закрываем файл
    fclose(file);
    
    return 0;
}
```